# TypeError: 'SimpleImputer' object is not callable

Tags: python, data-science

I'm working on 1 dataset to train that dataset I imported

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

Insted of

```
from sklearn.impute import Imputer
```

But I'm getting an error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b03cc58fb96b> in <module>
      3 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
      4 imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
----> 5 Imp=imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='median',axis=1)
      6 new=Imp.fit_transform(train.Age.values.reshape(1,-1))
      7 train['Age2']=new.T

TypeError: 'SimpleImputer' object is not callable
```

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

According to you code you import `SimpleImputer` only, not any other method so you cannot use `Imputer` as it is not defined in your code.
Either there is a method called `Imputer` in `sklearn.impute` then you should import it like this:

```
from sklearn.impute import Imputer
```

If you were referencing the variable you created line 4, you made a case mistake and you should use:

```
Imp = imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='median',axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that I get that after I posted the question but after changing that I'm getting same error.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow that's why I didn't know that how to edit question. Sorry for that I edited question. Try to help .

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, observed that there is some unnecessary code that's causing the issue. Your code can simply be -

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
new = imputer.fit_transform(train.Age.values.reshape(1,-1))
```